# Filters are getting reset when i click on page 2 or unable to apply filters on page 2

Tags: c#, html, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created a page where I'm using pagination. The issue is when I apply filter. It's getting applied only to the first page; when I click on the second page, the filter gets reset. If I apply the filter on the second page it takes me back to first page.

The following code is for the index page where I'll apply the filter.

```
<nav aria-label="DemandPaging">
    @await this.Component.InvokeAsync("Pager", new { pagingList = this.Model.Esas })
</nav>

<nav aria-label="Paging">
    <vc:pager paging-list="@Model" />
</nav>
<form asp-controller="Esa" asp-action="Index" method="post">
    <div>
        @Html.Label("Filter By:")
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedStatus,
       new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status))),
       "")
        <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EsaProjectId)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EsaProjectName)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmpName)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Designation)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StartDate)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EndDate)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Billability)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Allocation)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NblReason)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comments)
                    </th>
                    <th>  @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Esas)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EsaProjectId)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EsaProjectName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Designation)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Billability)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Allocation)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NblReason)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @*<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.CtsEmpId">Edit</a> |
                                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.CtsEmpId">Details</a> |
                                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.CtsEmpId">Delete</a>*@
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

The controller is as follows:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Index(EsaViewModel viewModel, int page = 1)
    {
        int pageSize = 8;
        var query = _context.Esas.AsNoTracking()
                 .OrderBy(s => s.EsaProjectId);
        Status result = viewModel.SelectedStatus;
        if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("PMOUser"))
        {
            if (viewModel.SelectedStatus.ToString() == "")
            {
                query = from x in _context.Esas
                        orderby x.Status descending
                        select x;
            }
            else
            {
                query = _context.Esas.AsNoTracking()
                         .Where(s => s.Status == viewModel.SelectedStatus.ToString())
                         .OrderBy(s => s.Status);
            }

        }

        viewModel.Esas = await PagingList.CreateAsync(query, pageSize, page);
        return View(viewModel);
```

Can please anyone help me with this? How do I get the filter to stay?

Comment: Have you tried using [cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_cookies.asp) yet? Could try to save the filters in a cookie and then retrieve that data on the next page. Could als try to put the filters in the url, and then passing the url variables to the next page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, apply filter on the second page it takes you back to first page.

I have a hunch that when you submit filter, the page parameter is null --> page is 1

So that, I suppose you place a hidden field in your form, that the place store current page

> (ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["page"]: get parameter
> name is page in your url. Ex: http://localhost/?page=2)

--> it'll send to controller and make the page parameter not null.

```
<form asp-controller="Esa" asp-action="Index" method="post">
    <div>
        //Get value page in your url
        @Html.Hidden("page", ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["page"])
        @Html.Label("Filter By:")
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedStatus,
       new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status))),
       "")
        <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EsaProjectId)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EsaProjectName)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmpName)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Designation)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StartDate)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EndDate)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Billability)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Allocation)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NblReason)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comments)
                    </th>
                    <th>  @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Esas)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EsaProjectId)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EsaProjectName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Designation)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Billability)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Allocation)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NblReason)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @*<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.CtsEmpId">Edit</a> |
                                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.CtsEmpId">Details</a> |
                                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.CtsEmpId">Delete</a>*@
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```